# Passing formatted strings between modules

Tags: python, string, win32com

Weird thing that was happening to me. I made myself my own module, located here.

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\NateMisc
```

I imported it into my python file.

```
import NateMisc
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

Which did work, however one of the functions decided to not work.

I defined a string as below, and tried to pass it to my module.

```
subj = 'Cleanup-{}-{}-{}.xlsx'.format(now.year,now.month,now.day)

NateMisc.send_notification(to,subj,body,attach)
```

The relevant parts of the module are as follows.

```
import win32com.client as win32
from __main__ import *
def send_notification(to,subj,body,attach):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = subj
```

I was getting the error on mail.Subject = subj as below

```
NameError: name 'now' is not defined
```

Now i fixed it by changing to the below, but I'm still not really understanding why it didn't work in the first place.

```
m = now.month
d = now.day
y = now.year
subj = 'Cleanup-{}-{}-{}.xlsx'.format(y,m,d)
```

Any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Hello, I was wondering if anyone has any input on this.

Edit: I still do not know how this happened

Comment: can you give the definition of now? it seems weird that the only thing you change to fix it was the answer to your original problem

Comment: i cant believe i did not include the definition of now, i apologize.

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

Comment: It is what I assumed but to be sure. Then sorry, I don't know how to help you because the first way works for me. And I don't see any reason why it should not as `subj` is a string in with ways in your main script before passing to the function from the module

Comment: yeah. thats about where i was. thanks for reading!